# PHP library to fill an array of dates for a given period?

Tags: php, period

I have a lot of values like this:

```html
+---------------------+-------+
|        Date         | value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2015-05-22 13:10:59 | 23,99 |
| 2015-05-22 13:20:19 | 23,8  |
| 2015-05-26 17:30:00 | 8     |
| 2015-05-26 19:00:00 | 125   |
| 2015-05-27 05:00:00 | -73   |
| 2015-05-27 06:00:00 | 30    |
| 2015-05-27 15:00:00 | 32    |
| 2015-05-27 16:00:00 | 33    |
| 2015-05-28 10:45:00 | 3     |
| 2015-05-28 10:50:00 | 3     |
+---------------------+-------+
```

And given a certain period (2015-05-20 -> 2015-05-30), in order to include all the dates for that period in the list, I need to fill the remaining dates. 
For better explain, I want something like this:

```html
+---------------------+-------+
|        Date         | value |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2015-05-20 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-21 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-22 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-22 13:10:59 | 23,99 |
| 2015-05-22 13:20:19 | 23,8  |
| 2015-05-23 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-24 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-25 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-26 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-26 17:30:00 | 8     |
| 2015-05-26 19:00:00 | 125   |
| 2015-05-27 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-27 05:00:00 | -73   |
| 2015-05-27 06:00:00 | 30    |
| 2015-05-27 15:00:00 | 32    |
| 2015-05-27 16:00:00 | 33    |
| 2015-05-28 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-28 10:45:00 | 3     |
| 2015-05-28 10:50:00 | 3     |
| 2015-05-29 00:00:00 | null  |
| 2015-05-30 00:00:00 | null  |
+---------------------+-------+
```

I know how to do this by code, but it has a lot of drawbacks, so I'm looking for a library to do so.

Any idea about any PHP library to work with stuff like this?

Comment: I don't get the question, you represent a database table so why not ask the database to return the dates using `BETWEEN()`?

Comment: You have to tell us .. what's your situation.

Comment: I'm doing that already, but I need to list the whole period (all the dates), even when a specific date doesn't have a value.

Comment: @victor the situation is the first part...that is what I currently have.

Comment: @KatsuMoto ... You need to use SQL Query IF THESE RECORDS are in a Table of a Database...

Comment: @KatsuMoto ... I can give you answer if you can tell me where did this data from...

Comment: I'm getting the data from a MySQL Database, but I don't have the complete period dates, I have some scattered dates only, and I have to complete the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i can't get you an Library, but it is really simple in php to do so, just use a function which gives you an Array with all the Dates:

```
function getDatesFromRange($start, $end){
$dates = array($start);
while(end($dates) < $end){
    $dates[] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(end($dates).' +1 day'));
}
return $dates;
}
```

use the result as keys:

```
$dateArray = array_fill_keys(getDatesFromRange($start, $end), null);
```

And then use the result from your mysql query to set the real values. So thats less then 10 lines of code, i think a library would be Overkill..
And if you use the getDatesFromRange Function only for this purpose, you can even shorten it more...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how to do it, what I was looking for was something like a library to make the process easier.